# How to calculate the # of steel wires required to prevent rupture of stacked, wired units

Tags: classical-mechanics, solid-state-physics

I wrap 6 units of a product with several wires. I then stack 5 of these wrapped units vertically. How do I calculate the minimum # of wires that I need to wrap the units so that the wires do not rupture/fail from the weight of the units on top of each other? I want to know if I can reduce the # of wires used to wrap the 6 units.

Comment: What material is the wire made of (what type of steel)?  What is the diameter of each wire?  What is the weight of each unit that is suspended by the wires?  Your question cannot be answered without a LOT more information.

Comment: How do wires, which have no compressive strength, support the weight of the upper units? Or is it the products which are supporting the products above them? Or are the products not rigid, e.g. flexible balloons?

Comment: (The word is "number", not "#". Or "quantity" if you prefer.)

Comment: I realize the need for more information, I was interested in what I need and what the calculations would be. I am trying to get the modulus and Poisson's ratio for the material. Not sure what else I need and the exact calculations required. The units are not suspended. 6 bales of pulp (unit)are wrapped with 5 wires. There are 5 units stacked on top of each other. The question is can we reduce the number of wires, and by how many, to reduce costs without creating a safety hazard. Minimum wires added are 2.

Comment: Isn't pulp somewhat variable in its physical characteristics? How severe are the results of packaging failure: someone has to spend half a day mopping up, or a small village is wiped out?

Comment: Each bale is a solid block of compressed dry pulp weighing approximately 0.2 tonnes so a unit is ~ 1-1.2 tonnes

Answer (score 0):

**There is a lot missing from this question to answer it.**

You need a mathematical model of the tension in the wires and this depends on the geometry of the wrapped objects, the interaction in the stacking, and any external loading (like cornering/braking loads).

Then convert the tension into stress, and using the material properties of the wire compare the stress to the yield strength of the material.

So if you are not an engineer, you need to find an engineer to do the calculations for you. If you want to go at it on your own, read up on statics, and engineering mechanics.

Details play a huge role in engineering, as subtle effects can be critical to the operation of something.